# WebLogic Virtual Directory Mapping Not Working

Tags: weblogic

I am having a frustrating problem with virtual directory mapping in my very simple WebLogic 11g application.  I installed WebLogic 11g OEPE, which installs WebLogic Server 10.35.  I believe that this is installed correctly, because I am able to deploy a much more complicated application that is working fine...except for my issue with virtual directory mapping.

I want to access files from a directory outside of the web application, H:\Backup.

Here is my **entire** application, and these are my **exact** files.

**wl_test/index.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>WebLogic Test</title></head>

<body>
<h1>This is another new test<br>
</body>
</html>
```

**wl_test/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**wl_test/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml**

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <virtual-directory-mapping>
         <local-path>H:/Backup/</local-path>
         <url-pattern>/files/*</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.txt</url-pattern>
    </virtual-directory-mapping>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

When I access the HTML file, '**http://localhost:7002/wl_test/index.html**', it loads perfectly fine.

However when I attempt to load either of the following two URLs, they both fail with a HTTP 404 error.  And yes, both of those files, one.ini and asdf.txt exist in the H:\Backup directory.

1. 'http://localhost:7002/wl_test/files/one.ini'
2. 'http://localhost:7002/wl_test/asdf.txt'

What could be wrong with this trivial setup?

I'm beginning to think I don't understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Well...I installed a server on a different system and, of course it worked perfectly.  So then I *removed* the server from my development workstation and reinstalled it and *it* works now too.

Should I delete this question now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what has changed and how to fix everything.

There were two problems with the virtual directory mapping.

First, the **local-path** cannot be a MS-DOS SUBSTed drive.  I don't understand why, but WebLogic doesn't like it.

Second, when the **url-pattern** contains a folder, like **/files/***, that folder must exist in the **local-path** directory.

Both of these are allowed in the JRun server that this is being ported from.

Sigh,
Randy Stegbauer

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: i want this local path to be dynamic, i need to change the local path from my java code

Comment: OH.  I don't know how to do that or if it's even possible.  Do you mean dynamic from one HTTP request to the next?  I would think about ways to do this from the within the OS itself, maybe by renaming folders or changing symbolic links.  If that's possible.

Also consider creating a new Stack Overflow question so that other people see it.

Comment: I was busting my head over this, after looking at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1039396 I resolved it. 
If the local-path is H:/Backup/ and the url-pattern is /files/*, then you should create a "files" folder inside Backup, Weblogic will look there for the files.

Comment: nMoncho THANK YOU!!! Your are my hero for today. Your research helped me with the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something a little goofy about the combination of multiple url-pattern elements.  Here's a sample showing the shared 404 file from my archives.

Part of the NotFoundWeb.war/WEB-INF/web.xml looks like this:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Part of the NotFoundWeb.war/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml looks like this:

```
<wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
<wls:local-path>d:\temp\notfound</wls:local-path>
<wls:url-pattern>*.html</wls:url-pattern>
</wls:virtual-directory-mapping>
```

I have a file on the file system:
d:\temp\notfound\error\404.html

So at runtime when I type something like:
http://localhost:7001/NotFoundWeb/somebadurl

I get the error page from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

The generatedReports and /app/reports are local folders in the file system. This way, you can put any type of files inside the generated Reports folder:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 8.1//EN" "http://www.bea.com/servers/wls810/dtd/weblogic810-web-jar.dtd">
    
<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
        <index-directory-enabled>true</index-directory-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>
    <virtual-directory-mapping>
         <local-path>/app/reports</local-path>
         <url-pattern>/generatedReports/*</url-pattern>
    </virtual-directory-mapping>
</weblogic-web-app>
```